# (Python) How do I take a random word, and split its letters into individual variables?

Tags: python

Attempting to make hangman without a tutorial, to actually test my skills a bit. Just trying to figure out how I'd take a word (e.g. "About"), and split it's letters into it's own variable, so I can make the actual letter guessing part.

```py
word=random.choice(wordBank)
letters=list(word)
```

I tried to use this to split up the letters, but I'm not sure if they are split into separate variables.

Comment: Have you tried printing the list? Because it would answer your question quite quickly.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you know in advance how many letters there are going to be?  A list is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Using `list(word)` to split up a word into characters seems just about right.

Comment: I did try printing it, but I wasn't sure if it actually made them separate variables, or just separated the letters.

Comment: Suppose `word = "foo"`, then `list(word)` yields `['f','o','o']`. I see no problem in your code.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the point of variables. Your `letters` list is exactly what you need: a list of the letters. Can you explain why you think you need them in separate variables? Perhaps we could help on that point

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I am quite new to coding in general, so I most likely have misunderstood it. I was planning on having each letter as it's own variable, so I can ask "what letter?" and then use an if statement to compare the user's input to one of the letters, and figure out if it's right or not.

Comment: @Archaniac Yes, you're going to want a list for that, exactly like you have now. The chief limitation of variables is that they're finite and have to be enumerated when you write the code. That means that if you have some data of unknown length (like an English word), you can't use variables to store each value of that data. When you find yourself wanting to do so, you want a list (or a dictionary if the data is keyed in a natural way)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve, you don't really want to be assigning each character to a different variable. Here are some ideas to get you started:

```py
letters=list(word)
```

Will take the `word` string and split each individual letter into a list (named `letters`). It is worth noting that strings are iterable in python so this will work for both lists and strings:

```py
for letter in letters:
    print(letter)
```

Or you could test if a letter is present in the list:

```py
if "a" in letters:
    print("a is in the word")
else:
    print("a is not in the word")
```

Given that you're testing your skills, it might be worth introducing yourself to functions:

```
def test_for_letter_in_string(word, test_letter):
    if test_letter in word:
        return True
    else:
        return False

test_for_letter_in_string("hello", "h")
#True
test_for_letter_in_string("goodbye", "h")
#False
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey there try and use a loop to iterate over the characters of the string and assign them as global variables dynamically.

```
my_string = "hello"

for i, char in enumerate(my_string):
    var_name = f"char_{i+1}"
    globals()[var_name] = char

print(char_1)    # Output: "h"
print(char_2)    # Output: "e"
print(char_3)    # Output: "l"
print(char_4)    # Output: "l"
print(char_5)    # Output: "o"
```

Comment: `enumerate` has a *start* parameter, which you could have specified as in `enumerate(my_string, start=1)`,  and then you would not have to be adding 1 to `i` in your loop. **But why are you even proposing that the OP do this when the OP was misguided in wanting to have separate variables to begin with?.**

Comment: @Archaniac I don't see why you really want to have separate variables for each letter. It just complicates a solution. See [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Booboo I'm pretty new to coding in general, so I had no clue there was a way to do it without separating all of them.